# Porting C code to C#

Tags: c#, c, embedded

As a part of my work, I have to port parts of firmware written in c to a gui software that is written in c#. So, I have to convert the c code to c#. I could have used the c code as it is and call it from the gui, but people in here decided to port instead of using c file as it is.

When I was going to through the code, I found something like this:

```
static xdata x y;
```

Then after some research found that xdata says the chip to store this variable in a external memory. Now the problem is how can I write that line in c#.

Thanks everyone and this wonderful community.

Comment: Are you really sure this is a good idea to do? You would probably be way better off P/Invoking it for numerous reasons.

Comment: are you porting from the embedded chip, to a PC or something similar or staying in the chip?

Comment: Yeah, I would be better off invoking them, but for some testing ease testers and people who will be validating the GUI wants us to port it. I think may be the chip is small to allocate/do stuffs with a big c code, this file is like 3000 lines. This is just one module, they have several other modules.

We Are creating a gui, which is going to stuffs instead of implementing those functions in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove it. `xdata` just a tip for the compiler to where to store the variable. If you remove it the C# compiler will figure it out on it own.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But how does the compiler know it has to store the variable on external memory? Sorry, I'm new to embedded systems programming, no sure how these compiler will take care of stuffs.

Comment: are you porting from the embedded chip to a PC or something similar or staying in the chip?

Comment: Basically controlling chip from gui. The ported c# is used to with a gui porgram to interact with the chip.

Comment: It is going to run on pc, which reads and writes values into the chip.

Comment: so you are safe to remove `xdata`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider porting your C code to a .NET C++ dll instead of C#.  This should minimize your porting problems.  The `xdata` keyword can be effectively remove by an empty macro.

Use something like the following in a header file in your C++ project:

```
#define xdata
```

The .NET C++ dll can easily be referenced by the C# GUI project.

Comment: That would be a nice idea. I have to discuss with the team about that. But just by using a xdata empty macro, I guess that will not do anything actually.

Answer (score 2):

Your question leaves out a lot of details. When I see "I have to port parts of firmware written in c to a gui software that is written in c#.", I would assume the "parts" being ported are not hardware related. However, maybe that is not the case and you are using something like the .NET Micro Framework. Are you going to be running the C# code on some form of embedded CLR, or is strictly going to run on a PC? If it's just going to run on a full Windows .NET platform. If the latter then you can ignore the xdata qualifier since C# has no analog to it.

Comment: What I have been told is instead of directly program things into firmware, software will be doing some stuffs. Yes, we are moving from embedded c to .Net c#. The software runs on pc but controls(reads and writes) a chip.

Comment: OK, How are you going to control the chip from the PC. Typically when I do something like this, on the chip I'll have a command parser that operates over TCP so that I can just send down command strings (you can also just any transport layer the chip supports, serial, USB etc). When porting you just need to isolate the hardware calls into an API for your command parser.

Comment: We basically created an API that our gui uses to read and write values from the chip. And a person who is working with me will be doing the API to the firmware gui software calls.

Comment: Good, then you probably just need to keep a log of anything that appears to map memory to a specific location. Many embedded chips support concepts like memory mapped I/O. Your embedded counterpart will need to know if you modify anything along those lines. If the embedded design had good separation of concerns that shouldn't be a problem. You need to be extra careful when you come across certain keywords. For example, C# supports the volatile keyword but it almost certainly isn't going to do what you need it to do when you move code that uses a volatile var from the embedded space to the PC.

Comment: Thanks Tod! I will checkout the memory mapped I/O.